# Format JSON after scraping it from URL

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to format the data that is being scraped from my API. It prints in JSON format as coded. However, my question is how can I format it to make it print data like this:

```
Product ID: 123456789
Physical Quantity: 20
Quantity Available: 20
```

At the moment, it prints such as this. It asks the user to input a product ID and then goes to the API to get product information.

```
    {
        "payload": [
            {
                "productId": "10229480",
                "quantityPhysical": 20,
                "quantityAvailable": 20
            }
        ]
    }
```

The Python code is as follows:

```
import json
import requests
from colorama import Fore, Style

# getting data from source
get_data = input(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + "Please enter a product ID to check stock level: ")
beep = requests.get("https://api.mywebsite.co.uk/shop/api/productsStock/" + get_data)
 
# pretty printing data
pretty_data = json.dumps(beep.json(), indent=4)
 
print(pretty_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may iterate on the dict `data['payload'][0]`

```
# beep = requests.get("https://api.mywebsite.co.uk/shop/api/productsStock/" + get_data)
# data = beep.json() # use that lines for real use

data = {
    "payload": [
        {
            "productId": "10229480",
            "quantityPhysical": 20,
            "quantityAvailable": 20
        }
    ]
}

for key, val in data['payload'][0].items():
    key_fmt = " ".join([x.capitalize() for x in re.findall(r"([A-Z]?[a-z]+)", key)])
    print(f"{key_fmt}: {val}")
```